# Nginx permission issue (404)

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

Trying to get let's encrypt setup using the webroot method, which creates and needs to access files in  the ./.well-known/acme-challenge/ directory. Everything there (including the manual test file I added) shows up as 404.

Going kind of crazy as I've tried variants of:

```
location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
}
location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    default_type text/plain;
}
location /.well-known {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

with no luck. I've also checked permissions on the folders and even set to 777. I'm pretty new to setting up nginx config so I'm sure there's an existing condition that's throwing it off:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://domain.com$1 permanent;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
}

server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
        root /var/www/domain.com/public_html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                client_max_body_size 32m;
        }
        location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your first `server` block has no `root` directive.

Comment: Oh man, thank you! Can you throw that in as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first `server` block needs a `root` directive to resolve local files.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for more.

Comment: Note, if you put the `root` directive should not contain `"/.well-known"` even if it's inside the `location` block

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/domain.com/public_html;
    
        # NOT
        # root /var/www/domain.com/public_html/.well-known;
    }

Answer (score 9):

As Richard Smith said, a `root` directive is needed. It can go in the `server` block or the `location` block.

Note, even if `root` is in the `location` block, the path should not contain `"/.well-known"`

```
location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
    root /var/www/domain.com/public_html;

    # NOT
    # root /var/www/domain.com/public_html/.well-known;
}
```

Comment: Does it matter where the root is? I assume scripts like certbot will parse the config to determine where this path is?